# log openvpn traffic by squid

Tags: squid, openvpn, network-traffic

is any way to log openvpn traffic (sites that users visited)?

i think because openvpn use tunnel and encrypt traffic cannot log visited websites, but in a server i saw that open vpn's users traffic is logged;
is anyway to do that?

Comment: Where are the clients with respect to the OpenVPN tunnel?  Does squid live on the same box as one end of the OpenVPN tunnel?

Comment: yes,squid and openvpn is in the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

openvpn provides you with encrypted point-to-point tunnel. so for instance you can hide your traffic crossing public internet. but traffic passing by router where you terminate the vpn tunnel can obviously be monitored.

when we talk about http - you can force it via transparent proxy - like squid or use passive methods - for instance [httpry](http://dumpsterventures.com/jason/httpry/) or good old tcpdump.